# Slash or Space in sphinxql in a faucet field does not work

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx, sphinxql

I have a query like this:

```
select id from myindex 
where match('main search keywords') and
myfilter in ('somevalue')
order by weight() desc limit 0,50
option max_matches=5000 facet myfilter limit 5000
```

And the sphinx conf has this attribute setting:

```
sql_attr_string         = myfilter
```

This query works perfect and I get results of the `main search keywords` filtered by the facet value `somevalue`

But the same query does not work if I have space (like this `some value`) or slash (like this `some/value`) in my query, (where of course the db has values with space and slash in them).

By "does not work", I mean it does not bring any results.

I also tried escaping the forward slash case, i.e. I used `some\/value` and even `some\\/value`, but it still did not return any results, although the db does have them.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

```
SHOW WARNING Result

Array
(
    [Level] => warning
    [Code] => 1000
    [Message] => 
)

SHOW META Result

[0] => Array
(
    [Variable_name] => total
    [Value] => 0
)

[1] => Array
(
    [Variable_name] => total_found
    [Value] => 0
)

[2] => Array
(
    [Variable_name] => time
    [Value] => 0.000
)

[3] => Array
(
    [Variable_name] => keyword[0]
    [Value] => 694
)

[4] => Array
(
    [Variable_name] => docs[0]
    [Value] => 199
)

[5] => Array
(
    [Variable_name] => hits[0]
    [Value] => 199
)
```

Comment: Is slash listed in charset_table?  Did you check yo see if anything via SHOW WARNINGS. And/or checked what SHOW META shows for the query?

Comment: @barryhunter I added forward slash to my charset_table, but it did not help.

Comment: @barryhunter also added the `SHOW WARNINGS` and `SHOW META` response to the post.

Comment: I even tried it using crc32() and md5() functions on both sides, i.e. in sphinx.conf inside the mysql query and during matching in php. But that does not work either. It shows same resultset with unrelated records.